# ¿Es válido utilizar el nombre de la propiedad en su misma declaración?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Quisiera saber cual es la diferencia entre estos dos conceptos de Get; y Set; en .Net c#
en este ejemplo, nombre y nombre1 pueden recibir y enviar un valor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public class Estudiante
{
  public string Nombre { get; set; } 

  public string Nombre1 

  {   get => Nombre1; 
      set => Nombre1=value;
  }

}
```

Comment: No soy experto, pero creo que el primero simplemente hace la operación por defecto, y en el segundo puedes implementar una serie de operaciones que quieres que ocurran al momento de establecer o leer un atributo de la clase.

Comment: es correcto lo que menciona @Christian , podrías, por ejemplo, calcular algo al momento de recibir una variable, si lo deseas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### La primera forma:

```cs
public class Estudiante
{
  public string Nombre { get; set; } 
}
```

Es una [propiedad autoimplementada](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) y definirlo de esta manera es útil cuando no necesitas agregar ninguna lógica adicional (cualquier código que realice tal acción).

Se le dice *propiedad autoimplementada* porque el compilador agregará una implementación de manera predeterminada, esto se lo puede comprobar usando [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/). Por ejemplo, el código anterior el compilador lo convertirá más o menos de esta manera:

```cs
public class Estudiante
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private string <Nombre>k__BackingField;
    
    public string get_Nombre()
    {
        return <Nombre>k__BackingField; // Implementación predeterminada.
    }

    public string set_Nombre(string value)
    {
        <Nombre>k__BackingField = value; // Implementación predeterminada.
    }
}
```

Como puedes ver, la propiedad como tal en realidad es transformado a métodos (get/set).

### La segunda forma:

```cs
public class Estudiante
{
  public string Nombre1 

  {   get => Nombre1; 
      set => Nombre1=value;
  }
}
```

Tiene un detalle importante a considerar: *Esto compila pero en realidad no funciona*, por lo que recomiendo que NUNCA lo intentes utilizar en un proyecto real porque puedes llevarte una gran sorpresa.

Intentemos compilar y ejecutar el siguiente código en un compilador online como [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i0Rg9H):

```cs
using System;
        
public class Estudiante
{
  public string Nombre1 
  {   
      get => Nombre1; 
      set => Nombre1=value;
  }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Estudiante es = new Estudiante();
        es.Nombre1 = "Dave";
        Console.WriteLine(es.Nombre1);
    }
}
```

Este programa da como resultado lo siguiente:

```
Stack overflow.
Repeat 261816 times:
--------------------------------
   at Estudiante.set_Nombre1(System.String)
--------------------------------
   at Program.Main()
Command terminated by signal 6
```

Con esta información podemos deducir que el error está en esta línea:

```cs
es.Nombre1 = "Dave";
```

O sea, está ocurriendo el famoso [stackoverflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow) y por lógica, existen varias formas para que ocurra este error, como, por ejemplo, llamar un método a sí mismo sin agregar un caso base (finaliza la recursión).

Para entender el *porque*, vamos a convertir el código anterior a código IL. Haga clic en este [enlace](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQPkGYACNQgUQGdgBXGMAQwDtgBTHAbx0OKOXQAZCAOQD2AWwBGAJ2bpCnQmy5zsSpQHNmwQgF4AfELFSZAbmWqu5TTv0iJ09NoBudCFWbH5AXxzfc2AsSoxOgA7OzyXGioEQoxqhTUtIwshMzkOoQMzADuZJQ09EzMABQAlB4q5lxpAHS2RrLahABEACJ0jszNFVWR6ACcxbX19uUxvp5AA===) para ver el código IL.

Podemos notar que el compilador convirtió el código a esto (es solo una manera de verlo):

```cs
public class Estudiante
{
    // Aquí sucede una recursión que no tiene fin.
    // Esto genera un stackoverflow.
    public string get_Nombre1()
    {
        return get_Nombre1();
    }

    // Aquí sucede una recursión que no tiene fin.
    // Esto genera un stackoverflow.
    public string set_Nombre1(string value)
    {
        set_Nombre1(value);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Estudiante es = new Estudiante();
        es.set_Nombre1("Dave"); //En esta línea ocurre el famoso "stackoverflow".
        Console.WriteLine(es.get_Nombre1());
    }
}
```

¿Es una locura? Claro que sí. El compilador no creo ningún campo privado de apoyo (el atributo como tal), simplemente sigue la lógica que esté escrita en C#.

Entonces, al final ocurrió este error porque el compilador está generando un código con un comportamiento inesperado para el usuario, por lo que la solución es **NUNCA** utilizar el nombre de la propiedad en los descriptores de acceso (get/set) **porque obligas al compilador a generar un código erróneo.**

Usted lo que debe usar es un [propiedad con campo de apoyo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties#properties-with-backing-fields):

```cs
public class Estudiante
{
  private string _nombre1; //campo de apoyo para la Propiedad "Nombre1".

  public string Nombre1 
  {   
      get => _nombre1; 
      set => _nombre1 = value;
  }
}
```

Esa es la forma correcta de hacerlo, de lo contrario, su programa no funcionará como espera.

**Nota:** Mencioné el [código IL](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/managed-code#intermediate-language--execution) porque es la mejor manera de saber como funciona realmente tu código de alto nivel.

Comment: Me quedó super claro, muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

En el primer caso:

```
public string Nombre { get; set; }
```

Estás ante una propiedad [auto-implementada](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties). Se comporta como una variable.

En el segundo:

```
string nombre;
public string Nombre {
    get => nombre;
    set => nombre = value;
}
```

La implementación la haces tu. Nota que en este caso haces referencia a otra variable. Aunque no es precisamente necesario. Cómo en esencia son funciones, siempre que devuelvas un valor o una variable del tipo requerido, el código funcionará.

Comment: pero no hay variable Nombre, solo tengo dos propiedades, nombre y nombre1, pero lo que si entendi es que es mas codigo hacerlo como aparece nombre1 al fin y al cabo de las dos formas funcionan igual

Comment: @DesarrolloSoftware No funcionan igual, el segundo código genera un *stackoverflow*, tenga cuidado con eso XD

Comment: @DesarrolloSoftware si esta respuesta no contesta tu duda, porque fue la respuesta aceptada? es mas, esta respuesta, aunque correcta, no es lo que mostras en tu codigo...